# Focus eventhandler for Textbox and dropdownlist using asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone tell me a event for focus on textbox and dropdown.(ie) If a tab comes on textbox or dropdown using asp.net web application.I searched but i can find for leave focus such as textchanged or selectindexchange.Pls provide me any reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can do things in following way:

Javascript code :

```
<script>
function myFunction(x)
{ 
  alert('Get Focus');
  //Do your stuff here.
}
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
Enter your name: <input type="text" onfocus="myFunction(this)">
```

Comment: Is it possible to handle the event in server side

Comment: no it is not possible. if you want to perform some server side coding than you can use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`myTextBox.Focus();`

But remember `myTextBox.Focus()` tries to set focus on the textbox element.
If the element visibility is hidden, `Focus()` will not work. So do make sure that your element is visible before calling `Focus()`.

Comment: i am using asp.net textbox if my focus comes to my textbox i want to call the server side method in asp.net web appln